# Make python re.sub look multiple times

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following code:

```
s = 'cucumber apple tomato'

def f(match):
    if match.group(2) not in ('apple', ):
        return '%s (%s)' % (match.group(1), match.group(2))
    else:
        return match.group()
```

How to make `re.sub(r'([a-z])+\s+[a-z]+', f, s)` output `cucumber apple (tomato)` ?

The problem is that regex engine tests only `cucumber apple`, not `apple tomato`.

Comment: So, you want to wrap with parentheses any word other than an `apple` that is not the first word in a string? Try `result = re.sub(r'(?!^)\b(?!apple\b)[a-zA-Z]+\b', r'(\g<0>)', s)`. To build a dynamic regex, use `fr'(?!^)\b(?!(?:{"|".join(words)})\b)[a-zA-Z]+\b'`

Comment: If your list is longer, do you want only the last item to be in brackets? What is the desired pattern?

Comment: Assuming you want to match space-separated groups of words and put the last word inside parentheses: `re.sub(r'((?:\b\w+\s+)+)(\w+\b)', r'\1(\2)', s)`.

Comment: There can be any number of words: 'cucumber apple tomato tomato apple cucumber tomato tomato' and the output should be 'cucumber apple (tomato) tomato apple (cucumber) tomato (tomato)'

Comment: The problem is that regex looks for two words and if there is no match it skips both words, doesn't try second word as first.

Comment: That means you want the logic I explained in the top comment, right?

Comment: I don't understand what is the first word in the string. 'tomato tomato tomato tomato'. on first step it becomes 'tomato (tomato) tomato tomato'. Now it checks '(tomato) tomato', not match, move further: 'tomato (tomato) tomato (tomato)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing lookahead:

```
>>> s = 'cucumber apple tomato'
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)(?=[ \t]+(\w+))', s)
[('cucumber', 'apple'), ('apple', 'tomato')]
```

That allows you to capture the second word in front of the first word without consuming the string.

Which you can turn into (what I >> think <<) is your desired result:

```
>>> [f'{t[0]} ({t[1]})' if t[1]=='apple' else t for t in re.findall(r'(\w+)(?=[ \t]+(\w+))', s)]
['cucumber (apple)', ('apple', 'tomato')]
```

---

In your comments, you have a different example with a different pattern for an answer. For that result, just use optional matches:

```
>>> s='cucumber apple tomato tomato apple cucumber tomato tomato'
>>> [f'{t[0]} {t[1]} ({t[2]})' if t[2] else f'{t[0]} ({t[1]})' for t in re.findall(r'(\w+)(?:[ \t]+(\w+))?(?:[ \t]+(\w+))?', s)]
['cucumber apple (tomato)', 'tomato apple (cucumber)', 'tomato (tomato)']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the information you've given in the comments so may not be exactly what you're looking for but:

> There can be any number of words: 'cucumber apple tomato tomato apple cucumber tomato tomato' and the output should be 'cucumber apple (tomato) tomato apple (cucumber) tomato (tomato)'

This regex will capture all non space characters after "apple" and before the end of the line while ignoring words finishing in "apple" and allowing it to be the first in the line.

```
(?:^| )apple ([^ ]*)|([^ ]+)$
```

For the example string
"apple cucumber pineapple tomato tomato apple cucumber tomato tomato"
it will select
"apple **cucumber** pineapple tomato tomato apple **cucumber** tomato **tomato**"